# ConcurrentHashMap size() performance

Tags: java, performance, concurrenthashmap

Whats the running time performance of `ConcurrentHashMap size()`?  Looking at the source (this is Java7) I can't figure it out, and Im not seeing it discussed in the docs.

Here is the code

```
 public int size() {
        // Try a few times to get accurate count. On failure due to
        // continuous async changes in table, resort to locking.
        final Segment<K,V>[] segments = this.segments;
        int size;
        boolean overflow; // true if size overflows 32 bits
        long sum;         // sum of modCounts
        long last = 0L;   // previous sum
        int retries = -1; // first iteration isn't retry
        try {
            for (;;) {
                if (retries++ == RETRIES_BEFORE_LOCK) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < segments.length; ++j)
                        ensureSegment(j).lock(); // force creation
                }
                sum = 0L;
                size = 0;
                overflow = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < segments.length; ++j) {
                    Segment<K,V> seg = segmentAt(segments, j);
                    if (seg != null) {
                        sum += seg.modCount;
                        int c = seg.count;
                        if (c < 0 || (size += c) < 0)
                            overflow = true;
                    }
                }
                if (sum == last)
                    break;
                last = sum;
            }
        } finally {
            if (retries > RETRIES_BEFORE_LOCK) {
                for (int j = 0; j < segments.length; ++j)
                    segmentAt(segments, j).unlock();
            }
        }
        return overflow ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : size;
    }
```

Comment: How about benchmark it for your target scenario? It's sure to depend on a large number of factors, especially level of contention.

Comment: I dont want to guess.  I need to figure out if I can access size every request or if it should only be done on a timer.

Comment: So you think benchmarking will result in guesswork? Obviously, you won't get an "authoritative answer" here because if there was one, it would have been in the Javadoc.

Comment: I am looking for the theoretical running time of this method.  Lots of methods in Java have amortized runtime limits, and also have exceptions. Why is this any different?

Comment: And the source of that data is in all cases the Javadoc of corresponding classes, isn't it? So guesswork is all you'll get, and benchmarks are a definite improvement over armchair speculation. Also note that those theoretical times are exclusively applicable in a single-threaded setting. Would you care about single-threaded performance of a concurrent map?

Comment: *"Why is this any different?"* - Well it is.  Why?  Because you can't generalize from the performance of one operation / algorithm to the performance of all of them.  It isn't a logically sound generalization.

Comment: so lets consider `put`.  Its complexity is O(1) right?  But in a threaded scenario it can be anything depending on the threading context at the time. So if someone asks whats the runtime complexity of put are you going to tell them to measure it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, my reading of the code is that the complexity is `O(1)`.

First, if you look at the rest of the code, you will see that `segments.length` depends *solely* on the value of `concurrencyLevel` when the map is created.  It doesn't change when the map is reallocated.

So, in the uncontended case, it is simple to see that the stuff inside the `for(;;)` loop will get executed twice, and that the number of iterations of the inner looks is `segments.length`; i.e. this is `O(1)` overall.

In the contended case, the performance is going to be worse because the `for(;;)` loop might get executed multiple times.  But I still think the complexity will be `O(1)` relative to the map size `N`.

---

But having said that, it looks like `size()` is an expensive operation, and it will be a concurrency bottleneck if the contention is sufficient that the algorithm has to fall back on locking the entire map; i.e. `retries` reaches `RETRIES_BEFORE_LOCK` (2 in the version I looked at).